# Fail to install Realtek Wi-Fi driver rtl8821AU

Tags: drivers, realtek-wireless

I've done a clean install of Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS. I'm trying to install a wi fi dongle to get internet access. The installation fails:

```
yoav@yoav-System:~/Documents/LINUX/Linux$ sudo chmod +x install.sh
yoav@yoav-System:~/Documents/LINUX/Linux$ ./install.sh
##################################################
Realtek Wi-Fi driver Auto installation script
Novembor, 21 2011 v1.1.0
##################################################
Decompress the driver source tar ball:
rtl8821AU_linux_v4.3.19.5_17672.20160506_BTCOEX20150921-58.tar.gz
.
.
.
rtl8821AU_linux_v4.3.19.5_17672.20160506_BTCOEX20150921-58
Authentication requested [root] for make clean:
```

And it won't accept my password.

Edit:
Tried sudo ./install.sh

```
yoav@yoav-System:~/Documents/LINUX/Linux$ sudo chmod +x install.sh
[sudo] password for yoav: 
yoav@yoav-System:~/Documents/LINUX/Linux$ sudo ./install.sh
##################################################
Realtek Wi-Fi driver Auto installation script
Novembor, 21 2011 v1.1.0
##################################################
Decompress the driver source tar ball:
rtl8821AU_linux_v4.3.19.5_17672.20160506_BTCOEX20150921-58.tar.gz
.
.
Authentication requested [root] for make clean:
bash: make: command not found
Authentication requested [root] for make driver:
bash: make: command not found
##################################################
Compile make driver error: 127
Please check error Mesg
```

Regarding using sudo -i. Command Dir produces nothing under root0@yoav-System:~

I have no idea how to navigate to the directory where the install.sh file is.

Edit 2:
Tried to install build-essential package:
sudo apt-get install build-essential

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package build-essential is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'build-essential' has no installation candidate
```

Does apt-get requires to be online? I am offline until I manage to install this driver.

Comment: did you try `sudo ./install.sh` either? I guess your root user has no password. Alternatively you can do `sudo -i` and than as root user execute the script.

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't get this to work. I updated the question.

Comment: With 'sudo -s' you remain in the path

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have the "make" executable.  Install the build-essential package:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

then try again.

Comment: This failed. I updated the question. Does this require me to be online? Is it possible to download these packages to a usb stick?

Comment: I think you can pull packages from a CD as well, but easiest is via internet.  Maybe you can connect a network cable to an internet-connected laptop and have that laptop share its internet on that interface.